# Printing integers store in variables in as8088

Tags: assembly, x86, increment, as88, x86-16

So I'm on the last step of my program and that is to print out a summary of sorts. I'm currently having issues printing out the numbers that I've stored in .WORD variables.
In this code I modify and output a translated string, I also increment variables used to count words.  At the end of this function I do a test print of the variable linect. As an output I receive a box full of numbers the lower right number increments up as I do more test prints once it reaches 4 it sends a empty line then a 6
example of the output:
[image]

```
translate:


    PUSH    BX
    PUSH    BP
    MOV BP,SP
    MOV BX,6(BP)

! GET CHARCT, WORDCT, LINECT Working

1:  CMPB    (BX),'\n'
    JE  4f
    INC (charct)
    CMPB    (BX),' '
    JE  2f
    MOVB    CL,(inchar)
    CMPB    (BX),CL
    JE  3f
2:
    PUSH    1       ! print that byte
    PUSH    BX
    PUSH    _STDOUT
    PUSH    _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8
    INC BX
    JMP 1b

3:  MOVB    CL,(outchar)
    MOVB    (BX),CL
    PUSH    1       ! print that byte
    PUSH    BX
    PUSH    _STDOUT
    PUSH    _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8
    INC BX
    JMP 1b

4:  CALL printnl
    INC (linect)



    !!!! Test print of linesect
    MOVB     CL,(linect)
    MOVB     (BX),CL
    PUSH     1
    PUSH     BX
    PUSH     _STDOUT
    PUSH     _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8
    CALL printnl
    POP BP
    POP BX
    RET
This is the code used to declare the variables
        .SECT .DATA
prompt1:
    .ASCII  "Enter a line of text: "
endpro:
    .BYTE   0
prompt2:
    .ASCII  "Enter 2 characters for translation: "
endpro2:    

outchar:
    .BYTE   0
inchar:
    .BYTE   0
charct:
    .WORD   0
wordct:
    .WORD   0
linect:
    .WORD   0
inword:
    .WORD   0
```

Comment: What's `SYS`? A macro? Anyway, your `WRITE` system call probably can't print integers. Either use a another system call that is able to do so (if there is one), or write a function that converts integers to strings. There are already numerous questions on how to do that conversion, so do a search.

Comment: SYS was described to me by the professor as a kind of wait time for the program but I could be mis-quoting that.

Comment: Found just the thing I needed thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PUSH (charct)
PUSH _STDERR
CALL printdec
ADD SP,4
```

Modified a program that converts a interger to a string for printing